# How to resolve...? Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in 'C:ect..'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications

**Steps done already that didn't work:**
removing package-lock.json, runing npm install and npm start again, same error occurs.

**index.js / Imports:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import data from './content.json';
import './index.css';
```

**Package JSON:**

```
{
"name": "base",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "rm": "^0.1.8",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "yarn": "^1.15.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

**Removing the browserlist from package does this and the same error again.**

[image]

Comment: Can you remove browserslist in your package.json file then run project.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the whole `node_modules`-folder along with the `package-lock.json`, and then run `npm i`?

Comment: @AnkitVerma chk the Image.. Removing the browserlist from package does this and the same error again.

Comment: Can you give a little more context?
Where does the package.json file exists, within project root?
Already tried to remove eslintConfig, to check is certain subdeps aren't installed correctly?

Comment: @Jezpoz that's done and didn't help me.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2534#issuecomment-340727156

Comment: @JeffreydeGraaf all the dependencies are installed and Package.json is within the root.

Comment: Create new react-app and copy your Old project  code, New react app  and Run npm i .